# Javascript code block in rmarkdown does not work

Tags: html, r-markdown

I'm trying to create an Rmarkdown document with a button to copy a text fragment. I've tested the code independently in an online HTML editor, and when I press the button, the text is successfully copied to the clipboard. I've then tried to get this to work in an Rmarkdown document, using a codeblock as recommended by the bookdown author Yihui Xie.(https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/). When the Rmarkdown document is compiled to .html, the button does not work (RStudio used to compile).

````
    ---
    author: "Nick Riches"
    output:
      html_document:
        number_sections: no
        toc: yes
        toc_float:
          collapsed: yes
      pdf_document:
        toc: yes
      word_document:
        toc: yes
    ---

    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
    ```

    ```{js, echo=FALSE}

    function myFunction() {
      var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
      copyText.select();
      document.execCommand("copy");
      alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);

    ```


    <p>Click on the button to copy the text from the text field. Try to paste the text (e.g. ctrl+v) afterwards in a different window, to see the effect.</p>

    <input type="text" value="Hello World" id="myInput">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button>
````

Answer (score 0):

I've found a package on github called klippy by Romain Lesur. This is how you can use it

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("RLesur/klippy")
```


```{r klippy, echo=FALSE, include=TRUE}
klippy::klippy(lang = "markdown")
```

```{markdown}
Here insert text to be copied
```
````

Full syntax reference at: https://rlesur.github.io/klippy/reference/klippy.html